# Prism 6 - Merge ConfigurationModuleCatalog with DirectoryModuleCatalog

Tags: c#, wpf, configuration, prism

I have recently working with Prism 6, and would like to reference core modules from an app.config (so they can be swapped out in future without recompile..the whole point of prism!). However, I would like to then add that functionality to extension modules for a plugin architecture, so would therefore like to merge the ConfigurationModuleCatalog with a DirectoryModuleCatalog object to facilitate a "plugins" directory.
My question:
Is there an "official" way to do it? I haven't been able to find a way, but my Google search terms were perhaps incorrect! Or do I have to hack it together by manually merging the catalogs on initialisation?

Comment: for Prism 7 see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54571914/prism-7-merge-configurationmodulecatalog-with-directorymodulecatalog

Comment: @JinJi Perfect, thank you! didnt like that the answer had a stale link in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very easy to do.  This sample shows you how to use an AggregateCatalog

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf/tree/master/Modularity/ModularityWithUnity

Comment: Thanks for that, knew I'd seen something but couldn't pin it down! Also, huge respect for your work online with Prism and blog, very good and easy to follow!

Comment: Thank you for the kind words. It keeps me motivated :)

Comment: Just a quick follow up from this one.. is it possible to load items into the container from the app.config? I have realised this is where the majority of  the core dll's need to be added! (I have clarified some of the terminology which I misunderstood) - im looking at currently doing this with a custom app.config section being processed in the container configuration method.

Comment: You will have to research the container of your choice to determine how to configure it via an app.config.

Comment: Thanks, i was just checking in to say I had a look through the prism source and the UnityContainer supports it with the addition of microsoft.practices.unity.configuration namespace. Thanks again for your time

Comment: The link doesn't seem to work anymore for me, only 404's :(

Comment: Ray, I have tried to find it in the github, with no luck, sorry! @BrianLagunas can you update the link please for this?

Comment: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf/tree/695a7ef7152978156c1e251cd20343574e411939/Modularity/ModularityWithUnity