# Prism 7 - Merge ConfigurationModuleCatalog with DirectoryModuleCatalog

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-container, prism

I would like to use both:

```
protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
{
    return new ConfigurationModuleCatalog();
}
```

and

```
protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
{
    return new DirectoryModuleCatalog() { ModulePath = @".\Modules" };
}
```

I found this question:

[Prism 6 - Merge ConfigurationModuleCatalog with DirectoryModuleCatalog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34955695/prism-6-merge-configurationmodulecatalog-with-directorymodulecatalog)

But the link in the answer is dead, it returns 404.

I also searched for the "AggregateCatalog" that was mentioned in the answer - I looked here:

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/tree/master/Source/Prism/Modularity

and here:

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/tree/master/Source/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/Modularity

but I didn't find it...

Is there any way to do this in Prism 7 with Unity?

Comment: Did you try to return a merged `ModuleCatalog`? `var a = new DirectoryModuleCatalog() { ModulePath = @".\Modules" }; var b = new ConfigurationModuleCatalog(); return new ModuleCatalog(a.Modules.Concat(b.Modules));`.

Comment: it almost works. the error is in the last line, for the constructor parameter: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Prism.Modularity.IModuleInfo>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Prism.Modularity.ModuleInfo>'

Comment: Please see my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
{
    var a = new DirectoryModuleCatalog() { ModulePath = @".\Modules" };
    var b = new ConfigurationModuleCatalog();

    return new ModuleCatalog(a.Modules.OfType<ModuleInfo>().Concat(b.Modules).OfType<ModuleInfo>());
}
```